# Stop runnable in Android on button click

Tags: android, timer, handler, runnable

I'm new to Android. I am trying to stop runnable on button click. From the solutoins I have googled this seems an awful lot straight forward but for some reason even after the code to stop runnable is executed; it just keeps going.

I have done my declarations and implementations outside OnCreate();

```
//create handlers
    Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //do something to the main thread
            new ViewVideoClass().execute();
            timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 1);
        }
    };
```

And when a specific button is clicked, I try to stop the runnable like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Preview Video button clicked
            //this display video feedback from the ip camera
            //The web service sends a frame every interval and I display next frame in 
            //timer (runnable) so that it looks like a video
        if(v.getId() == viewVideoButton.getId()){
            timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 1);
        }
        //Rec button clicked
        if(v.getId() == startLoggingButton.getId()){
            if(serviceOffLine == true){
                //firstly stop the handler to release the thread and allow other requests to be made to the service
                timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
                flagButton = 1;
                //when anyone of the video buttons is clicked, the other should be disabled
                startLoggingVideoOnlyButton.setEnabled(false);

                if(startLoggingButton.getText().toString() == "Rec"){
                    new StartLoggingClass().execute();
                    startLoggingButton.setText("Recording");
                    startLoggingButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    startLoggingButton.setTextSize(12);

                    //disable the button, to prevent the user from clicking it again
                    startLoggingButton.setEnabled(false);
                    startLoggingGpsOnlyButton.setEnabled(false);
                    //enable the stop button
                    stopLoggingButton.setEnabled(true);
                    //maybe enable the handler here

                }else{
                startLoggingButton.setText("Rec");
                startLoggingButton.setEnabled(true);
                startLoggingButton.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
                startLoggingButton.setTextSize((float) 18.0);

}
```

When the [ViewVideoButton] is clicked; the timer is started. Ideally I would like to stop it when the [StartLoggingButton] is clicked. But for some reason it just keeps running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about setting up a flag in timerRunnable, like this

```
Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //do something to the main thread
        new ViewVideoClass().execute();
        if (mFlag) {
            timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 1);
        }
    }
};
```

And set up the flag in your button click listener.

Comment: When I debug it works, but when I just run the application it does not.

Comment: Well... I guess you don't manage that flag well. Are you forgetting to set it back on false ? Try installing the app on your device without running form the debugger. Then open it and see if it works. It may only work one first time, then the flag remains true.

Comment: Also, if you post your code it would be easier to find the problem

Comment: Okay let me post my entire code, but I will do that in 4 hours or so

Comment: I was putting the new ViewVideoClass().execute(); inside the if statement

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

Removes all runnables from the queue... straight forward :)